# If statement returning else regardless

Tags: php

I have a PHP code that gets an id number and then checks if the id exists in the database. If the id is in the database it echos `Item Added` if not it echos `That id is not valid`

(Well at least that is what it is supposed to do!)

Right now it echos out `Item Added` regardless.

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
$id     = $_GET['id'];

if ($action == 'add') {

    // Check if the id matches one in the database 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE id='$id'");

    if ($result = 0) {

        echo 'That id is not valid!';
    }
    else {

        echo 'Item Added';
    }
}
```

My url for the get actions look like this:

```
../shopping-functions.php?action=add&id=977
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are using the assignment operator instead of comparison in your if statment – i.e. you use `=` instead of `==`. Unfortunately, this is not the only mistake.

`mysqli_query` returns a MySQL resource, so just comparing it to 0 will not be true, unless the query actually fails. Instead, you need to look at the actual result data from the resource object you get back. An easier solution would be:

```
if ($action == 'add') {

    // Check if the id matches one in the database 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM items WHERE id='$id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {

        echo 'That id is not valid!';
    }
    else {

        echo 'Item Added';
    }
}
```

So instead of selecting the number of entries with the specific id, you just select the id itself if it exists and then you count the results you get back.

On an unrelated note: Your code is also vulernable to MySQL injections and you should instead be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

`=` is assignment

`==` is comparison.

Change:

```
if ($result = 0) {
```

to

```
if ($result == 0) {
```

Update:

You also need to retrieve the number of rows from your query properly, like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='$id'");
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row_cnt == 0) {
```

Comment: And 0 equates to `false`, hence why the `else` statement executes.

Comment: It is still returning the else result regardless

Comment: Have you echo'd $result to make sure you're getting what you think you should?

Comment: If you switched to `==`, and the else still always shows, then `result` is not 0.

Comment: I get an error when I echo out `$result`, In the query I am counting the amount of rows for the specific id. How would I return the `COUNT`

Comment: @j08691 Downvote because it's simply wrong. $result is not an integer, it's a MySQL object/result set.

Comment: @j08691 He's looking for a solution to his problem - you pointed out one fault, you didn't solve the problem. So no, the MySQL part is very relevant.

Comment: Your update does not solve the problem either. You're selecting the count and then counting the number of rows. The number of rows will always be 1 since there will always be a count, regardless of the count being 0 or 1.

Comment: Deleting your comments and silently making an update after I point out your mistake. How classy. ;)

Comment: @kba - My replies, and your obsolete comments, are not pertinent any longer so I deleted them. I was also updating my answer when you posted your last comment. Didn't feel like keeping this dialog going any further. And you can blow the classy out your ass. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($action == 'add') {
// Check if the id matches one in the database
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE `id`='$id'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
if($row[0] == 0) {
echo 'That id is not valid!';
}
else {
echo 'Item Added';
}
}
```

You were checking it with a mysql resource before, which was wrong. Also you used an assignment operator (=) rather than a comparism operator (==) just like every one said.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result = 0) {

        echo 'That id is not valid!';
    }
```

is assigning result, you need to use `if($result == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, using one = sign is **assignment**, not comparison.

Please refer to the [Comparison Operators documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

[image: PHP Comparison Operators]